# Javascript / Regex: strip first <p> if it matches a critheria

Tags: javascript, regex

So I am getting a HTML content from the API and sometimes it would come in this format

```
<p>::type/12</p>
<p>Some content</p>
<p>Some more content</p>
```

and sometimes will not have the first paragraph...

what I would like is to parse that html snippet and extract relevant information as an object with following properties
**type**, **time**, **content**

so in the previous example it should translate to:

```
data = {
    type: 'type',
    time: 12,
    content: '<p>Some content</p><p>Some more content</p>'
}
```

I also have the array of expected types (no more than 10)
allowedTypes = ['type1', 'type2', ...];

so if the first p contains ::type2/ than it's a valid object needing parsing, otherwise just do

```
data = {
    type: undefined,
    time: undefined,
    content: '.... all content here'
}
```

I have no experience with regex, how would I approach this?
Also worth mentioning I am working with angular, so no jQuery functionality

Any ideas?

Comment: don't use regexp for html....

Comment: that's why I was told many times, but don't know any other ways to solve this

Comment: If your data is limited to the format that you've suggested, then I would argue you aren't really parsing HTML. What you have is far more limited. I would use regex in this case. And I would be drummed out of the software world as a heretic. By the time I finish writing this my rep will be reset to 0 and my account suspended.

Comment: You would need to feed the HTML to an HTML parser.  Isn't there a library you can leverage?

Comment: Well if you're using some *particular* API and its response formatting is reliable, you can get away with it (sometimes).

Comment: yeah, the response is reliable, and there is not much there... just light HTML that is very limited by the editor.... (p, b , h3 and i tags)....

Comment: @JosephMarikle: no. except for angular stuff, no other libraries I could leverage... and ng does not offer anything in particular.

Comment: What about whitespace?  Can `<p>       ::type/12</p>` occur?

Comment: Just because you're using Angular doesn't mean you can include another JS utility library.

Comment: if this is being done in the browser I would say use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the html into document object and use DOM methods to grab the elements individually. Then access their text and use a regex on that instead of the whole html string.

Comment: @PatrickEvans: is happening before going to the browser.... when handling the API response.

Comment: @JosephMarikle: it might.

Comment: You mean server side? Like on nodejs?

Comment: @PatrickEvans: no. When it comes from the server. It happens in browser, of course... but in the angular controller (component) and not in the view... not injected into the DOM yet

Comment: It doesn't need to be injected into the actual page's DOM, DOMParser parses html/xml into a separate document object that you can use like any other document object, eg `document.querySelector('p')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it without using a regualar expression to parse the HTML

```js
function getObject(str) {

  var temp = document.createElement("div")
  temp.innerHTML = str

  var data = {
    type: undefined,
    time: undefined
  };

  var elems = temp.getElementsByTagName("p")
  var match = elems[0].textContent.match(/::([^\/]+)\/(.+)/);
  if (match) {
    data.type = match[1]
    data.time = match[2]
    elems[0].remove()
  }

  data.content = temp.innerHTML;

  console.log(data) 
  return data
}

var str1 = "<p>::type/12</p><p>Some content</p><p>Some more content</p>"
var str2 = "<p>Some content</p><p>Some more content</p>"
getObject(str1)
getObject(str2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex fetching the type and time if the structure of the first paragraph is consistent between all results. Based on your example, I would say this regex should work:

`/<p>::([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)<\/p>/`

It captures the letters after <p>:: and before / and also captures the numbers between / and </p>

You can find the matches with the exec method:

```
var results = /<p>::([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)<\/p>/.exec(text);
var type = results[1];
var time = results[2];
```

For the content, you could use this regex in replace as well

```
var content = text.replace(/<p>::([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)<\/p>/, '');
```

Note: this will only work if all results are formatted like you provided. If some result is different, you need to take care of that as well...

Comment: Thanks...this helps a lot! The combination of this and @epascarello will do the trick! Thanks